# Break tuple in RDD to two tuples

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, iterable

I have an `RDD[(String, (Iterable[Int], Iterable[Coordinate]))]`
What I would like to do, is to break the `Iterable[Int]` to tuples, that each one will be like `(String,Int,Iterable[Coordinate])`

For an example, I would like to transform:

```
('a',<1,2,3>,<(45.34,32.33),(45.36,32.34)>)
('b',<1>,<(46.64,32.66),(46.67,32.71)>)
```

to

```
('a',1,<(45.34,32.33),(45.36,32.34)>)
('a',2,<(45.34,32.33),(45.36,32.34)>)
('a',3,<(45.34,32.33),(45.36,32.34)>)
('b',1,<(46.64,32.66),(46.67,32.71)>)
```

How is done is Scala?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use flatMap:

```
rdd.flatMap {case (v, i1, i2) => i1.map(i=>(v, i, i2)}
```